# Why is uniqueness needed in order to use the symbol $-v$?

Tags: linear-algebra

In the book *Linear Algebra Done Right*, the author first proved the uniqueness of additive inverse, then said that the notation $-v$ now makes sense.

He does not explain why. So, I want to clarify whether my understand is correct.

If additive inverse is not unique, there are more than one additive inverse of $v$. As $-v$ just implies one additive inverse, it cannot be used.

Did I get it right?

Comment: Well, ordinarily, when you use a notation like that you want it to refer to one particular thing, not to a class of things (as might be the case if there were more than one additive inverse to $V$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A priori, there could be two different elements $w,w'\in V$ satisfying $v+w=v+w'=0$. Now, if we want to define the symbol $(-v)$ as an element of $V$ satisfying $v+(-v)=0$, then in order for this to really make sense, we should be sure that we're picking out one element. If not, expressions involving $"(-v)"$ contain ambiguity.